# Android Canvas - Bitmap pixels is not being reset to the original when clearing paint strokes

Tags: android, canvas, paint, pixel, grayscale

After painting some pixels to grayscale in my current image using getPixel() and setPixel(), I wanted to clear the strokes that are created. However when I set each pixel of the current image to the pixels of the original image, it does not do anything. Not sure why clear doesn't erase any of the strokes in the current image..

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            for (Integer i  = 0; i <= resizedBmp.getWidth(); i++ ){

                for (Integer j  = 0; j <= resizedBmp.getHeight(); j++ ){
                        //Paint newPaint = new Paint();
                        //int grayColor = grayBmp.getPixel(Math.round(j), Math.round(i));
                        resizedBmp.setPixel(i, j, originalBmp.getPixel(i, j));
                    }
                }

            postInvalidate();

            //can.drawBitmap(originalBmp, 0, 100, null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a first part to this question?

Comment: Sorry, this is the overall question. There is no first part. :D

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: I have edited my code and description.

Comment: Sorry, you can ignore this questions. It works now!

Comment: sorry.. It is not workign any more.. Pls help if possible.